# Log4J logging File and Resource Exception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, log4j, eclipse-rcp

i want to create a log file using Log4J in an Eclipse RCP application. Before initializing the file appender i check if the file exists in order to delete it if necessary :

```
IResource logFile = parent.findMember(fileName);
if(logFile != null) {
    logFile.delete(true, null);
    logFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO, null);
}
```

Then i configure my file appender :

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%m%n");
FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
fileAppender.setFile(fileName);
...
fileAppender.setAppend(false);
fileAppender.activateOptions();
logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
```

When the logging process is terminated i refresh the file like this:

```
IFile logFile = parent.getFile(new Path(fileName));
logFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO, null);
```

The file is properly displayed in a treeviewer but if i want to delete it i get this exception :

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
```

I have not found a way to properly refresh the workspace.

Do you have any advice ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any more details in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response ! Step by step debugging, I finally found that It was not possible to delete the file because it was used by another thread : it is necessary to close the file appender once logging is finished and I was not doing this :-| Again sorry for the delayed response and thanks for your help.